# Need an IF-ELSE inside a CASE-WHEN choice

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I've got an existing stored procedure that looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
...
    CASE PX.Client.value('(Type)[1]', 'varchar(25)')
      WHEN 'Sole Proprietor' THEN 'SPR'
      WHEN 'Partnership' THEN 'PAR'
      WHEN 'Corp (C)' THEN 'COR'
      WHEN 'Corp (S)' THEN 'SCO'
      WHEN 'LimitedCorp' THEN 'LLC'
      WHEN 'Trust' THEN 'TRU'
    END AS MyStructure,
...
INTO #Prod 
FROM 
  @XMLIN.nodes('/MyDataset/MyRegistration') AS PX(Client)
```

Everything works great except I need to change the logic. Right now if Type is "LimitedCorp" then MyStructure is always "LLC".  But I need to change it so that it sub-divides MyStructure based on the TaxClassification like so (pseudo-code):

```
...
WHEN 'LimitedCorp' THEN 
    IF PX.Client.value('(TaxClassification)[1]') == 'Partnership' THEN 'LP'
    ELSE IF PX.Client.value('(TaxClassification)[1]') == 'SCorp' THEN 'LLS'
    ELSE 'LLC'
WHEN 'Trust' ...
```

In my .NET code this would be a piece of cake!  I'm not very strong on my stored procedure syntax though!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest another `case`:

```
WHEN 'LimitedCorp' THEN 

    case 
       when PX.Client.value('(TaxClassification)[1]') == 'Partnership' then 'LP'
       when PX.Client.value('(TaxClassification)[1]') == 'SCorp' then 'LLS'
       else 'LLC'
    end

WHEN 'Trust' THEN 'TRU'
```